# Error in query: Invalid JSON string when Creating a Chart from a Spreadsheet? GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

Why am I getting  the error Error in query: Invalid JSON string when attempting to create a chart from a spreadsheet using the Google example script from their documentation [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets)?

I can't figure it out.  The only thing that I changed is the spreadsheet URL.  The rest is directly from the documentation example.  I provided all of my code below.  Any help you guys could give would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Brandon

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
    .evaluate()
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
};

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
};
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
     google.load("visualization", '1', {packages:['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
      'https://docs.google.com/a/sleschool.org/spreadsheets/d/1TRcHxsLuunRUPgn-i-h3OcVvh0TNp_VhJrNBI3ulMlA/edit#gid=0');
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart'));
  chart.draw(data, { legend: { position: 'none' } });
}
</script>

<title>Data from a Spreadsheet</title>
</head>

<body>
<span id='columnchart'></span>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<div id="EntireSite">

  <div>
    <?!= include('Chart'); ?>
  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE`  change it to `HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME` that way it worked for me to run the code of the documentation you added.